# Jpa Hibernate Spring Jpa repository query on Hebrew value

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have a SpringBoot Application.

this is my controller :

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin("*")
public class PeopleController {
    @Autowired
    private PeopleRepository poepleRepository;

     @RequestMapping(value="/chercher", method= RequestMethod.GET )
     public Page<People> chercher(@RequestParam(value="mc", defaultValue="") String mc, 
             @RequestParam(value="page", defaultValue="0") int page ,
             @RequestParam(value="size", defaultValue="5") int size){
         mc = "%"+mc+"%";
         return poepleRepository.chercher(mc,  new PageRequest(page, size));         
     }

}
```

Like you can see, I have in my repository a method called chercher. Its purpose is to search by keyword on Poeple entity.

That is the method in the interface:

```
@Query("select p from people p where p.name like :x or p.surname like :x")
    public Page<People> chercher(@Param("x") String mc, Pageable pageable);
```

All it's ok when I search by english character, but when I search by Hebrew character I have zero result.

That is my application properties for this connection:

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/poeple?useSSL=false
```

Comment: just a comment but you hava a typo in people. Its nothing major.

Comment: Can you explain me what you say please?

Comment: `@Query("select p from poeple p where p.name like :x or p.surname like :x")`
poeple is written incorrectly. people is written correctly.

Answer (score 1):

After search I found the solution but I let this post online to help somebody else that meet the same issue.

I added Encoded character in the connection like that and it work for me:

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/poeple?useSSL=false&useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8
```

Comment: Your solution is universal. Works for Czech language too. Proofed.